# Effect of Network Performance on Database (RDS)

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I would like to know the effect of Network Performance (also the exact name for the metric used by AWS RDS instance types) on a DB.

I am loading Graph database with data at scale using parallel processing (multiple Pods in Kubernetes).

I noticed that by simply changing from one RDS instance type to one more powerful, and monitoring the DB metrics in AWS console, performance is doubled.

*Performance figures that are doubled are*:
VolumeWriteIOPs - doubled
Network Throughput - doubled
VolumeReadIOPs  -  tripled

As the better instance type has more CPU, RAM, Disk, and possibly network performance (i believe there is an 'invisible' network performance tiering that is not shown in the instance specs), I suppose my question really is -- **if there is a *(hypothetical)* instance with same CPU, same RAM, same disk performance, what difference does network performance alone make to a DB?**
[image]

Do DBs and RDS DBs process everything slower if the network performance is lower?
Or does it respond at the same speed, but only serve less connections (making the others wait)?

In my use case they are Kubernetes Pods which are writing to the DB, so does it serve each Pod more slowly, or is it non-responsive above a certain point?